# Create a new line whenever an array value reaches more than 10 characters

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, newline

Here is my code, but it isn't dynamic. What I need is it will automatically create new line if array value is greater than 10.

```
<?php
$limit = 10;
$newline = explode(" ",$caption);

$count = count($newline); //count number of array values

$nlimit = strlen($newline[0]) + strlen($newline[1]);

if($limit >= $nlimit)
{
    echo $newline[0] . " ",$newline[1];
}
else
{
    echo $newline[0] . " ","<br>". $newline[1];
}
?>
```

Comment: Not completely clear what you are asking... - but what if you loop over your string one character at a time and insert newLine when character count modulo 10 equals zero?

Comment: Could you show an example caption and the output you are expecting ...

Comment: This question is a bit Unclear because it doesn't have a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
$caption = "im trying to figure out how to create a new line whenever an array value reaches more than 10 characters";

$lineCharlimit = 10;

$captionWordsArray = explode( " " ,$caption ); 

$line = '';

foreach( $captionWordsArray as $index => $word )
{
    if( strlen( $line .$word ) > $lineCharlimit )
    {
        echo $line ,'<br>';
        $line = $word;
    }
    else
    {
        $line .= ( $line == '' ? '' : ' ' ) .$word;
    }
}
echo $line;
```

Will output :

```
im trying
to figure
out how to
create a
new line
whenever an
array value
reaches
more than
10
characters
```

But for an output like below ( no line is less than 10 characters unless it is the last word ) :

```
im trying to
figure out how
to create a
new line whenever
an array value
reaches more
than 10 characters
```

Modify code as below :

```
$caption = "im trying to figure out how to create a new line whenever an array value reaches more than 10 characters";

$lineCharlimit = 10;

$captionWordsArray = explode( " " ,$caption ); 

$line = '';

foreach( $captionWordsArray as $index => $word )
{
    $line .= ( $line == '' ? '' : ' ' ) .$word;

    if( strlen( $line ) > $lineCharlimit )
    {
        echo $line ,'<br>';
        $line = '';
    }
}
echo $line;
```

Comment: Good attempt but some words are missing in your output?? "to", "how", "a", "whenever", ...

Comment: @Floris I have realized just after posting my answer and updated it now . Thanks of pointing it though .